# How to handle `ngIf` with async pipe values?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular8

I am trying to implement the `ngIf` with using `async` pipe. but not works. any one help me here?

here is my html:

```
<div class="response-container">
    xx {{response | async | json }}
    <div class="failed-error" *ngIf="(response.responseFail | async )">
        {{response.message}}
    </div>
    <div class="success-msg" *ngIf="(response.responseSucc | async) === 'true' ">
        {{response.message}}
    </div>
</div>
```

in the above `xx {{response | async | json }}` it prints as:

`xx { "responseFail": false, "responseSucc": true, "message": "success" }`

But why this is not works with `*ngIf` condition?

Comment: are there any errors that are shown in the console?

Comment: you need to bind bind value to async, so when that value is evaluated it will return true or false, eg. `response | async as _response ` but i would add that to response container, then inside your failed-error i would check like this  `*ngIf="_response.responseFail` instead of you asnyc.

Comment: @JohnKane yes, getting  no errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `response` is a data source while `response.responseFail` is not one. Try this:

```
*ngIf="(response | async )?.responseFail"

*ngIf="(response | async)?.responseSucc  === 'true' "
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to access the object after the async pipe =>

```
*ngIf="(response | async )?.responseFail"
```

ex =>

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvmqzm

edit : ethan got here first.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the previous answers, you shouldn't use the async pipe on the same observable several times.

Better do this:
(naming observabkes with $ is best practice)

```
<div *ngIf="response$ | async as response" class="response-container">
    xx {{response | json }}
    <div class="failed-error" *ngIf="response.responseFail">
        {{response.message}}
    </div>
    <div class="success-msg" *ngIf="response.responseSucc">
        {{response.message}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And since those div's only differ in class you should consider using ng-class